# How to use access token from response using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, token, response

So am making a login application that sends username and password, and the server replies with access token....am trying to save this token for later use but i really cant. here is my code, and the server response incase you need it
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var PhoneNumber: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
    //***************************************LogIn**********************************************\\
    @IBAction func Login(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://goollyapp.azurewebsites.net/Token") else {return}
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "username=" + PhoneNumber.text! + "&password="+Password.text!+"&grant_type=password"
        print(postString)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your backend? Have you tried simply returning it inside the response body instead of the header?

Comment: I wouldn't make a token public, and yes that does look like a token...it should be in your response object, I don't know your backend, but as @murphguy stated, it would be better to return a JSON object holding your token data instead of returning it in the header

Comment: You can convert the json token into a dictionary and then it can be used using key value pair, later it can be created as a singleton for multiple VC .

Comment: well actually now the token is appearing......i wanna know how to use it.....here is the updated code:

Comment: let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let response = response {
        print(response)
        }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print (json)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

Comment: Please just let us know the response data format except the token string.

Comment: Optional({
    ".expires" = "time";
    ".issued" = "Time";
    "access_token" = "Token was here....lol";
    "expires_in" = "somenumbers";
    "token_type" = bearer;
    userName = "my username";
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you declare the `json` variable replace with:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
```

Then you can access the token with:

```
let token = json["access_token"] as! String
```

(after receiving a successful JSON response)

You can then implement a Singleton as follows:

```
class Token {

    // Can't init a singleton
    private init() { }

    static let sharedInstance = Token()

    var tokenString = ""

}
```

Comment: am getting an error when using : let token = json["access_token"] as! String

Comment: Replace `let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])`, with `let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the token in a variable for using it later , try this
(key being the corresponding name of the key in your response object)

**`let token = httpResponse?.allHeaderFields["SECURITY-TOKEN"] as? String`**

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            let token = httpResponse?.allHeaderFields["SECURITY-TOKEN"] as? String
                print(token)
 }
 task.resume()
```

Comment: anyways this way is actually working....:let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])  as! [String: Any]
        let token = json?["access_token"] as! String
            print(token)
}
 task.resume()
//the only problem am facing is that i want to use this token from another class @Naishta

Comment: how about creating an object of that class, and accessing this token property ?, or other approach being injecting this property to where ever you need it